# If the date is falling on weekend or not in maximo

Tags: maximo

I want to create a condition such that it checks if the date entered in the date-field is falling on weekend or not. Is it possible in MAXIMO7.6?

Comment: Yes, this is possible in Maximo. But you haven't indicated whether you're trying to do it in an autoscript or an escalation or a conditional expression or a condition node in workflow or a relationship. And you haven't shown us what you've tried.

Comment: i wanted to do it via conditional expression manager... and i can do it now... i have used `TO_CHAR (:<field_name> , 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT', 'SUN')` as an expression in condtion...

Comment: If you have other suggestions please share, it would be good as knowledge purpose

Comment: That's the approach I was planning to take.  You should add your solution as an answer to this question.